# Server responded with a status of 414 (Request-URI Too Large) for WMS call of GeoServer

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I get "Server responded with a status of 414 (Request-URI Too Large)"  when trying to get the source for layer after applying a very big cql_filter.

Details:

I have a Layer 'L' with features for one whole country. Now i want to apply filter on this layer such that only part of country should be loaded. Currently I am using below function to achieve it.

wmsLayer.getSource().updateParams({'cql_filter': filterstring});

This works well for smaller filter strings. But when it is too big server throws error.(Due to the fact that get call has length constraint).

Can anyone help me with this issue,please.

Comment: use POST requests? or a more efficient (shorter) filter

Comment: In our case filterstring holds the details of the polygon coordinates to identify the boundary of particular region. I will check for that option as well. But i would like to know if we can achieve this using POST call.